# Best way to perform version control on an embedded linux project?

Tags: version-control, embedded-linux

I'm starting work on a new embedded Linux project.  The project will consist of an embedded board running Linux, some drivers (possibly some custom drivers), and an application on top.  I am working with another person and we need a way to put the project under version control.

I have used git for many projects before and I find it great, but I'm wondering what the best way would be to put this project into git; do I create separate repositories for the OS, drivers, and application?  Do I put everything into one giant repository?  Do I not put the OS under version control, but just the application?

Another question: do I put just the Linux source that we've used under version control, or the end product?  What about the whole filesystem that will be running on the board?

I would appreciate any thoughts on this.

Thanks!

Marlon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding Git:

- putting everything under one giant repo is generally a bad idea (especially when you need to clone said "giant" repo around)
- you should put under version control what needs to have a *source code history*: if you don't intend to actually modify the Linux kernel source (but just reference the exact version of said kernel you are using for a particular version of your project), then the OS needs to be stored elsewhere (an artifact repository like Nexus for instance).
- Same goes for the drivers: if you change their source codes, put them in their own Git repo and reference them as submmodules (you would be using a "source dependency").
  If you don't change their sources but use directly a binary, store it in an artifact repository (you would use them as a "binary dependency", which usually isn't stored in a VCS).

Comment: Thanks VonC, that's helpful.  I will follow your advice.

Comment: One more question: since we are using a semi-custom linux distribution, and may be making configuration changes to the distribution as the project progresses (ie. adding scripts to automatically run a program on startup, changing settings in system files such as /etc/network/interfaces), how should we distinguish between what things go in git and what things do not?  It seems like it would be difficult to put those types of things under version control without having the whole filesystem under version control?

Comment: @Marlon: you could: a/ ignore all the Linux kernel source b/ `add -f` only the few files you are modifying (i.e. you can "force add" files that should normally be ignored due to your `.gitignore` setting). That way, you could extract a Linux source code based on the Linux version you have references, and then overwrite the files with the few you had actually versioned in your Git repo.